# Customize Rails' Default Resourceful Route Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

## TL;DR

I'd like to change the default behaviour of Rails resourceful routing, to move the `create` path for all resources so that it's a POST to `/resources/new` rather than `/resources`.

## The Setup

Let's presume a resourceful route specified like so:

```rb
# routes.rb

resources :events
```

The actual routes that will be generated are:

```rb
$ rake routes

    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    events GET    /events(.:format)          events#index
           POST   /events(.:format)          events#create
 new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)      events#new
edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format) events#edit
     event GET    /events/:id(.:format)      events#show
           PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           PUT    /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           DELETE /events/:id(.:format)      events#destroy
```

N.B. that the `create` action is triggered by a POST to the `/events` path.

Now, if I want to change that path, I can do it "manually", on a per-resource basis:

```rb
# routes.rb

# I've placed the routes in this order, and used `as: "new_event"`,
# to avoid generating an `events_new` path helper.

post 'events/new' => 'events#create', as: "new_event"
resources :events, except: [:create]
```

Here are the generated routes:

```rb
$ rake routes

    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
 new_event POST   /events/new(.:format)      events#create
    events GET    /events(.:format)          events#index
           GET    /events/new(.:format)      events#new
edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format) events#edit
     event GET    /events/:id(.:format)      events#show
           PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           PUT    /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           DELETE /events/:id(.:format)      events#destroy
```

Great! The `create` action is now triggered by a POST to the `/events/new` path, rather than the `/events` path.

Every other route/helper behaves exactly as before — including a GET to `/events/new`, and the `new_event` path/url helpers.

## The Question

Rather than manually overriding every `create` action, is there a way to just change the default path used for that particular action?

Failing that, what other means could I use to change a bunch of resourceful routes, so that their create action would be moved to `/new` as above?

Thanks!

Comment: my guess is that you'll have to monkey patch [resources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/048235b5642c1d33055926946d918b8427e19f5c/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1348) to do this, but I __strongly__ encourage you _not_ to do this - Rails is all about conventions, and this would confuse the hell out of other devs that would read your code. One more explicit way to do things would be to use a [routing concern](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) containing the modified post action and add `except: :create` to each `resources` call.

Comment: plus, you can also define a `custom_resources` method that would do what you already do manually, calling the original `resources` in the process.

Comment: The suggestion in your second comment is what I've ended up doing. It works well enough. If you wanted to rewrite it as an answer, I'd mark it correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your life simpler by adding a module that does the overriding for you in a single place.  for instance:

```
module MyResources
  def my_resources(resource_name, opts = {}, &block)
    opts = opts.merge(except: [:create])

    resources(resource_name, opts, &block)
    post "#{resource_name}/new" => "#{resource_name}#create", as: "new_{resource_name}"    
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper.__send__ :include, MyResources
```

Then in your routes.rb you can do:

```
my_resources :events
```

Comment: Where would you recommend putting such a module? In the routes file? In, say, `app/services`? In `lib`? In an initializer?

Also, I'm not super up on my ruby. Is the way you're using `__send__` kosher? That seems like a monkey is being patched, possibly against its will.